# Ionic 3 : Clear InAppBrowser cache for Windows platform

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I am using salesforce authentication into my hybrid app(Windows 10).I have integrated InAppBrowser plugin to load a url in a web view.

I am facing issue when someone logout from app so cache is not getting clear.

I have also tried following code but options parameter is not working for windows platform. its only working in android and ios platform.

```
var options = "clearcache=yes;clearsessioncache=yes";
console.log(authUrl);
//Wait till the cordova platform is ready before triggering the inappbrowser plugin
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
 this.inAppBrowserRef = new InAppBrowser().create(authUrl, '_blank', options);
    });
```

Is there any alternative way that I can clear all cache associated to the InAppBrowser for windows platform?

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: Are you solve your problem I face sameone. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.
Once cross check with other URL may be issue with website url or windows app.

You are saying for Windows platform, is it working fine for Android and iOS?
thank you